# How to customize user registration in Joomla 3.7?

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, user, registration, joomla-3.7

Now that Joomla 3.7 supports custom fields, can anyone point me to documentation or a YouTube video that outlines how to customize user registration? I assume that additional work is also required to view these fields in user management in the administrative view? If so, what needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an easy way to do it just install the [Easy Profile](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/easy-profile/) component from the JED. It integrates with registration and with advanced fields in the user's profile which they may edit. I use it a good bit, very simple to setup and manage all of the custom fields you want with direct integration.

Answer (score 0):

As of now Content & Contact components are supporting custom fields.

Ref: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_custom_fields/What_components_are_supporting_custom_fields

Comment: That documentation is incorrect. I just checked and fields are supported in user management. Unfortunately it doesn't appear that the user profile plugin was updated to support fields. I'm guessing that I'll need to a custom user profile plugin. I was hoping that someone has had some experience with this new feature and could impart their knowledge to save me time and from re-inventing the wheel.